# v4l2-ctl - Parameters list?

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian, v4l2

I got this script on the Internet and tried to find a comprehensive list of parameters on Google but no success:

```
# Record a video
v4l2-ctl --set-fmt-video=width=800,height=600,pixelformat=4
v4l2-ctl --stream-mmap=3 --stream-count=100 --stream-to=$1
exit
```

Do you guys know how can I rotate the camera?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here the command to show all parameters and usage:

```
v4l2-ctl --help-all
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to find a control to manipulate a register in the camera to rotate the data before it comes out of the camera.  If your camera driver supports that level of control via v4l2 (not all drivers do), then this command:

```
v4l2-ctl -l
```

will list all the controls that the camera driver supports.

In your case I'd expect the controls to have names like "h_flip" or "v_mirror".